# I used two 'setState' inside a handleChange of input, for searching on the array. why the search is unseccesfull?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have an array of the names of cities. also, I have an input that I want the any input value to be searched on the array, and **synchronously** show the input's placeholder according to city's name that **started** with input value, whenever that user typing a character.

***a part of cities.json:***

[
"Aberdeen",
"Abilene",
"Akron",
"Albany",
"Albuquerque",
"Alexandria",
"Allentown",
"Amarillo",
"Anaheim",
"Anchorage",
"Ann Arbor",
"Antioch",
"Apple Valley",
"Appleton",
"Arlington",
"Arvada",
"Asheville",
"Athens",
"Atlanta",
"Atlantic City",
"Augusta",
"Aurora",
"Austin",
"Bakersfield",
"Baltimore",
"Barnstable",
"Baton Rouge",
"Beaumont",
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
"Wilmington",
"Winston",
"Winter Haven",
"Worcester",
"Yakima",
"Yonkers",
"York",
"Youngstown"
]

**index.jsx:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import cities from "./cities.json"; //cities is an array.

class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: '',
            placeholder: ''
        }
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            value: e.target.value
        });
        for (let i = 0; i < cities.length; i++){
            if (cities[i].startsWith(`${this.state.value}`)){
                return this.setState({
                    placeholder: cities[i]
                });
            }
        }
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input value={this.state.value} placeholder={this.state.placeholder} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

But two issues:

**1- Use two setState:** Do second setState use result of first setState?

**2- Output is not expected:** typed value is not synchronous with placeholder value. placeholder is shown when the input is cleared(while the placeholder must be empty,too). also it only shows first city, with any starter letter. e.g if I type "Akro" or "Alba", it shows "Aberdeen" instead "Akron" and "Albany", as placeholder. as well as if I type "Baton", it shows "Bakersfield" instead "Baton Rouge"(note the array).

**my output:**

[image]
[image]

**expected output:**

[image]

What is your solution? :)

Comment: Once you start typing inside an input, the placeholder text is replaced by what you type. The logic you're trying to implement involves CSS as well (most likely). I'm thinking a separate `div` with an absolute positioning and `z-index` for name suggestion.

Comment: @GabrielLupu "a separate div with an absolute positioning and z-index for name suggestion" ? Is possible you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `setState` function is async, so if you want to use the newly state you have to provide a callback to `setState` and use the new state inside it. So, for example, in your case you have to do something like:

```js
handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        value: e.target.value
      },
      () => {
        if (this.state.value) {
            for (let i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
                if (cities[i].startsWith(this.state.value)) {
                    return this.setState({
                        placeholder: cities[i]
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        return this.setState({ placeholder: ''})
      }
    );
  };
```

In order to display the placeholder correctly you need to do the following changes inside the render:

```js
render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ position: "relative" }}>
        <input value={this.state.value} style={{ fontFamily: 'Arial', fontSize: 14 }} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <span style={{ position: "absolute", top: 0, left: 0, padding: '3px 4px', fontSize: 14, fontFamily: 'Arial', opacity: 0.5 }}>
          {this.state.placeholder}
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: It still shows suggested placeholder only after of that become empty input. as well as by above code, suggested placeholder is always the name of last city. If I place "return" before 'this.setState'(similar to myself question that I edited, and not your answer), output will be the same my output that I indicated in question.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi I updated the answer, check it now.

Comment: pretty good :) espicially when the placeholder is cleared when the input is empty. only there is a small problem. focus is removed from the input, when I click on span text(placeholder), and for again writing, I have to click on the part of input that not include span. I want to checking maybe I can solve it. thanks :)

Comment: As a result, If the secondary setState wants to use the first result, should we put the second setState inside the first setState?

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi what do you mean with "first" and "secondary" setState?

Comment: it means: this.setState({ placeholder: cities[i] }); is placed inside the main setState, to search based on the latest input value. beacuse if be seperated(like my question) the search will be based on a previous input value.

Comment: Yes if have to base some calculation on the state after a `setState` you have to use the callback parameter of the `setState` function, otherwise you'll end up using an unsynced value.

Answer (score 0):

@Marco Nisi is correct but according to your question you want the saw city suggestions. @Arman placeholder is only displayed when there is no value in the input box. but you can use the datalist provided in the html. Please find the link to the working solution [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fiddle-forked-viqmt?from-embed).

```
import React from "react";
import cities from "./cities.json"; //cities is an array.

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: "",
      placeholder: "",
      suggestions: []
    };
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState(
      {
    value: e.target.value
      },
      () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        suggestions: []
      },
      () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
          if (cities[i].startsWith(`${this.state.value}`)) {
            this.setState({
              suggestions: [...this.state.suggestions, cities[i]]
            });
          }
        }
      }
    );
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
    <label htmlFor="city">Choose your city:</label>
    <input
      value={this.state.value}
      placeholder={this.state.placeholder}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      list="suggested_cities"
      name="city"
      id="city"
    />
    <datalist id="suggested_cities">
      {this.state.suggestions.map((suggestion) => {
        return <option value={suggestion} key={suggestion} />;
      })}
    </datalist>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Link to the fiddle for working example. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fiddle-forked-viqmt?from-embed

Comment: This have two problem. 1- I want to suggestions be similar to my expected output in question(not as list). 2- Suggestions are illogic, sometimes.